# Docker-compose not calling the healthcheck test endpoint

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to put in place a healthcheck mechanism for one of my containers, but so far, I was not able to make it running.

The container is starting ok, but for I don't know what reasons, docker-compose doesn't call the test endpoint (no requests coming from docker compose are hitting my breakpoint), nor is it complaining or restarting the container on which the healthcheck is configured.

There is nothing wrong with the test endpoint, as if I issue curl request from the host system, those requests are visible, when I'm debugging the endpoint.

Any idea why docker-compose is not calling the test endpoint?

My docker compose file looks like this:

version: '3.8'

```
services:
  middleware:
    image: middleware
    labels:
      logging: "promtail"
      logging_jobname: "containerlogs"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: 2
          memory: 8G
    build:
      context: ./target
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: --both
    environment:
      NODE_ID: ${NODE_ID}
    depends_on:
      - mw-db
    networks:
      mw-network:
        aliases:
          - middleware
      default: {}
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -f http://localhost:8081/system/healthcheck || exit 1
      interval: 30s
      retries: 5
      timeout: 10s
    volumes:
      - /data/disk1:/data:rw
 .............
```

My docker-compose version is: docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
My host system is: Fedora release 36

As test parameter, I've already tried, without success, the followings:

```
"curl -f http://middleware:8081/system/healthcheck || exit 1"
"curl -f http://middleware:8080/system/healthcheck || exit 1"
["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8081/system/healthcheck"]
```

UPDATES:
I'm seeing the same behavior with  Docker Compose version v2.24.6 on Fedora 39

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the missing curl from the tested container, as the healthcheck tests are being done from within the container. For details you may check this discussion: https://github.com/docker/compose/discussions/11585